# Optimize grep operation on big files

Tags: linux, bash, grep, do-while

I have two files `list.txt` and `purchaselist.txt` which are fairly large and am trying to get the latest purchase details (there are duplicates in purchaselist).

Lets say that below are the file contents:

`list.txt`

```
1111
2222
3333
```

`purchaselist.txt`

```
0001 1111 210.00 abcd 10 A 151234 181234 .... 
0011 1111 300.00 abcd 10 A 151000 181222 ....
0022 2222 110.00 abcd 10 E 151111 181000 ....
0099 2222 200.00 abcd 10 A 151222 181999 ....
0033 3333 110.00 abcd 10 A 151000 181222 ....
0044 0044 500.00 abcd 10 A 151999 181333 ....
8899 4444 800.00 abcd 10 A 153333 181777 ....
```

Am doing this using `grep` and a simple do while loop. Here is my command:

```
while read line; do tac purchaselist.txt | grep -m1 $line; done < list.txt >> result.txt
```

My expected output is, which am getting already looks like this:

```
0011 1111 300.00 abcd 10 A 151000 181222 ....
0099 2222 200.00 abcd 10 A 151222 181999 ....
0033 3333 110.00 abcd 10 A 151000 181222 ....
```

The above output is derived by picking the latest row from `purchaselist.txt` file for which I used `tac`. The value in `list.txt` appear as column number 18 in `purchaselist.txt`. The problem here is that files are huge. `list.txt` contains 580k records and looking for these records in `purchaselist.txt` which has ~1.7M records. The above script has been running for almost 20hrs and hasn't reached halfway. How can I optimize the processing time here?

Comment: Second line in output should be `0099 2222 200.00 abcd 10 A 151222 181999 ....`, right?

Comment: Yes, my bad. corrected.

Comment: There's nothing simple about a do while loop, it just looks simple when written incorrectly. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is slow because for every word in `list.txt` you read the whole `purchaselist.txt`, and in your case, it will be read 580K times. In addition, bash doesn't run fast on large iteration.

If other methods are acceptable, you can use `datamash`:

```
datamash -t ' ' -g 1 last 2 < purchaselist.txt
```

- `-t ' '` field delimiter = space
- `-g 1` group by field 1
- `last 2` last value of field 2

BTW, `4444` is not in `list.txt` but shown in final output, so I assume that `list.txt` is not required. If that was a typo, you can use `datamash -t ' ' -g 1 last 2 < purchaselist.txt | grep -f list.txt`.

Furthermore, if `datamash` is not yet installed and you do not have privilege to install packages you can use `awk` instead:

```
awk 'ARGIND==1{a[$0]}ARGIND==2{b[$1]=$2}END{for(i in a)if(i in b)print i,b[i]}' list.txt purchaselist.txt
```

This command consists of three parts `ARGIND == 1` `ARGIND == 2` `END`:

- `ARGIND == 1` means argument index 1 (you may regard it as `argv[1]`, `list.txt`)
- `a[$0]` $0 means the whole line, put it in a dictionary
- `b[$1] = $2` create another dictionary storing the price (`$2`, the second field) of each item (`$1`), existent values are overwritten in this way
- `END` after these two files are processed
- `for (i in a) if (i in b)` if both in `file.txt` and `purchaselist.txt`
- `print i,b[i]` print the key and the value

**Edit**
For non-GNU `awk`, one may use

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{b[$1]=$2}END{for(i in a)if(i in b)print i,b[i]}' list.txt purchaselist.txt
```

**Edit**
OK... If you have multiple fields:

```
tac purchaselist.txt | sort -suk2,2 | grep -f list.txt
```

- `tac` make newest come first
- `-s` stable sort to keep the original order
- `-u` take unique ones for `-k2,2` (the second field) that is, only keep the first record for a specific key value
- `-k2,2` Use field from 2 to 2 as key
- `grep` filter out unwanted items

Comment: Yes, it was a typo and `4444` is not required in the final output as I had mentioned. Unfortunately as you foresaw, I wouldn't be able to install `datamash` package. Could you please elaborate the awk command for clarity?

Comment: @NobleAbraham just added.

Comment: `GNU Awk 4.1.4`

Comment: Oh, ok. Looks like it's a GNU extension, couldn't find it in POSIX spec or mawk manual. Consider adding a note that your awk solution will not work with all awks, or use `FNR==NR` to check if current file is the first one on the command line

Comment: Thanks @dibery for the additional detail, but there are 2 problems as I see. The file `purchaselist.txt` contains way more than just those two columns (I avoided them to keep the question simple but that caused this :-/) which means that `b[$1] = $2` to overwrite existent values wouldn't work as there could be other columns that might have got updated and that is the reason I used `tac` in my script as the latest row holds the most updated data.  Lastly, the output should also not be limited to `print i,b[i]` but the entire row from `purchaselist.txt`

Comment: Then give a complete sample and your desired output so that people will come up with a solution that you can use.

Comment: Anyway, added another method.

Comment: @dibery just made the edits as requested. I tested your script from edit for multiple fields but the unique filter is not required as the latest record is all thats needed.

Comment: By unique `sort` will only keep the first record for each value in that key field. After `tac` that's the latest record.

Comment: I updated your script to use field 18 as I had added to the post and tested it just three id's in `list.txt`: `tac purchaselist.txt | sort -suk18,18 | grep -f list.txt` and it returned just one result which belong to the first entry i.e. `1111` correctly. No results for `2222` or `3333` although they exist is `purchaselist.txt`

Comment: Tested fine on my side. This uses GNU `sort`, if that makes difference. Try sorting without -u and see the result is sorted or not as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ tac purchaselist.txt | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $2 in a{print; delete a[$2]}' list.txt - | tac
0011 1111 300.00 abcd 10 A 151000 181222 ....
0099 2222 200.00 abcd 10 A 151222 181999 ....
0033 3333 110.00 abcd 10 A 151000 181222 ....
```

Change $2 to $18 if that's the matching field number in your real data. The above will work on unsorted data and shouldn't have any memory issues as it's only storing the 580k small key strings from list.txt in memory in the awk command.

Comment: Is there any difference using `a[$2]` in place of `$2 in a`? One preferred over the other?

Comment: `#2 in a` is preferred. `a[$2]` will create that entry in  the array and so use up memory for every $2 value in purchaselist.txt. `$2 in a` just tests if that $2 already exists so `$2 in a` is the most efficient wrt memory usage. Also `$2 in a` is a simple hash lookup while `a[$2]` is a hash lookup and then a test of the value that resulted from that hash lookup so `$2 in a` is also the most efficient wrt speed of execution. You;d also have to use `a[$1]++` or `a[$1]=1` in the `NR==FNR` section to be able to use `a[$2]` later which uses even more memory and execution time.

Comment: Those are the nuggets I was looking for. In my thought process, test `a[$2]` would have simply be a `non-zero/zero` test as `a` was already filled where `FNR==NR`. I was concerned that `$2 in a` may require more than a simple access/test of the array element. From what I get from you, `$2 in a` is optimized for that case (and avoids creating an entry for all the `$2` that are not already present in `a`). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following requires that the files be sorted on the column that they are to be joined on. The examples were sorted so is it not unreasonable to assume that the real files can be or already are sorted.

```
join -j 1 list.txt purchaselist.txt | tac | rev | uniq -f 1 | rev | tac
```

I don't know if this would perform better but it at least does not contain two levels of nested loops. It correctly produce the desired output once the test inputs have been amended to include `4444` in the `list.txt` file.

```
1111 300.00
2222 200.00
3333 110.00
4444 800.00
```

Tip: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113898/how-to-merge-two-files-based-on-the-matching-of-two-columns

Comment: This presumes that both input files are sorted.

Comment: Unfortunately the files are not sorted. They are concatenated in ascending order based on occurrence and that is the reason am using `tac` with `grep -m1` to pick the latest record.

Comment: @NobleAbraham how big are the files? Are they so big that you don't have the space to sort them?